# preventDefault not working with tab(9) keyCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I using a `keypress` event for <kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>. But for some reason the code only runs with <kbd>enter</kbd>. By pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> it just does the default <kbd>tab</kbd> action and ignores the code. Please help.

```
onEnterAddWord: function(ev) {
        var kc = ev.which || ev.keyCode;
        if (kc === 13 || kc === 9) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            this.$el.find('.add-word-input input').trigger('blur');
            this.$el.find('.viewbox').trigger('click');
            console.log('check');
        }
    },
```

Comment: Try using `onkeydown` instead of `onkeypress`

Comment: can you create the fiddle??

Comment: Weird keydown works instead of keypress. What's the difference. Thanks. @RobH

Comment: See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html keypress is only fired when an actual character is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **keydown** instead of **keypress**

Modifier and non-printing keys does not fire the keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `ev.stopImmediatePropagation();` which will prevent other eventListeners to fire?

Comment: Tried this didn't work. But thanks, I got it working by changing keypress to keydown.